# Get only gallery folder : Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, gallery

I would like to implement a Picture Chooser, since there's a bug with the **Recent image foler** and the **Download Folder** the Android app crashes when selecting an image from these two folders, I would like to hide them, or open directly the Gallery folder without showing the Folder chooser panel,

This is my actual code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult (intent, 1000);
```

and in the on Result Method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    String uri = intent.getDataString ();
    String absolutePath = getRealPathFromURI (uri);
    String compressedFilePath = compressImage (absolutePath);

    encodedResult = base64File (new File (compressedFilePath)); //String
}

protected String getRealPathFromURI (String contentURI, UIView uiView) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = ((ContextWrapper) uiView).getContentResolver ().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}
```

So when I select an image from a folder like : Gallery, Pictures etc... It works just fine. But for the 2 folders : **Download** and **Recent** it crashes and gives me :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Or maybe there is a more correct way of doing that which I'm not aware of it ?

Do you have any idea about this ? How can I achieve that ? Thanks.

Comment: Your Android app crashes? Why does that happen?

Comment: Agreed. Rather than reducing functionality for your user -- and in ways that will be incompatible across devices -- I would focus on getting help for your existing problems.

Comment: Thank you. And yes I agree, this is wiser. I have updated my question with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it crashes and gives me

That is because you are assuming that any `Uri` can be converted into a `File`. That has never been supported.

Use a `ContentResolver` and consume the `Uri` via `openInputStream()` (or `openOutputStream()`, if appropriate).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. I'll digg in that direction. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please help me here i did posted a question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883092/android-action-get-content-does-not-update-download-dir-files