# Android ACTION_GET_CONTENT does not update download dir files

Tags: android, filepicker

I am facing an issue while choosing a file from **Downloads** directory using **ACTION_GET_CONTENT**.

If I delete any file in ES explorer or file manager in my local storage, those deleted files aren't removed in **downloads** dir while opening in my app.

Any changes in **downloads** dir dosen't get reflected in chooser.

To choose a file I am using the below library

https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser.

Here I attach my screenshot please have a look:

[image]

Comment: It seems like no problem with your code, problem with device, so check in other device and if same issue then type your code here for file picker.

Comment: Ok let me have a look on it and get back to it.

Comment: @Vickyexpert no in other devices also it remains the same it does not reflect in download dir outside not inside internal storage,please have a look on my screenshot.

Comment: You want to send file to after choosing file?

Comment: I also facing same problem. It seems like media-scanner should have to be triggered as it is not updating Directory. And note that if I add a new File to Downloads directory, then it appears but along with that old deleted file. I don't know why that file is shown there if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

You must have to call  `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)` while deleting the file, where `uri` is the URI of the file to delete. This will update Media Store, which holds URIs of all files. So, when **ACTION_GET_CONTENT** opens the downloads directory, the file you deleted won't appear here.

Comment: i am not asking for deleting the file inside the app my problem is if i delete any file outside in my local storage for (eg:ES Explorer) in download dir then go to my app and their if i open the download dir with  ACTION_GET_CONTENT their i can see the deleted file in list.